# How can you compare $Shape in flow on a deep nested object?

Tags: reactjs, types, flowtype

The issue I have is that I want to create a function that takes an object that is a small part of a larger object and deep merges it. However, I want it strongly typed to catch if/when the 'big' object's shape changes.

I am including a contrived example below.

```
/* @flow */

type ContrivedType = {
  nested: {
    name: string,
    optionalValue1?: string,
    optionalValue2?: string,
  }
}

let contrived: ContrivedType = {
  nested: {name: "Required Value"}
}

type UpdateObject = $Shape<ContrivedType>

const update = (updateObject: UpdateObject): void => {
  contrived = {
    ...contrived, 
    ...updateObject,
    nested: {
      ...contrived?.nested, 
      ...updateObject?.nested
    }
  }
}

update({nested: {name: "should work", optionalValue1: "should work"}})
update({nested: {optionalValue1: "won't work"}})
```

[Here you can see the results](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCcAdhgE4CWAbngCYAquBAvGAN6phgl4DOGegC4OXbjwCGAWzwiBVEgHMANGO5wcGSqQkwAaroCueAIwB+ORUpLV4sBq079RvACYLYedZViAvqn9UGDwMMABjUitaOhFiMipopnwwNk5uXgFhDhJpWTAAIgAlPABHQ0pyejADGGN8-0DsZIBVHDoJQQB5ACMAKzww0LYAEgBlAAsJfAAeOKj6JLwAPnQIkgEwQzaO1jAACi32rr6BjBFWo7we-sGAShFqOEo6FKXRbjX5l9S1MAA6AGfBL0ZRgX4Av6HHbXU62cQZQQxd52f6AyLAuhmP4IkFglGoyHbY43DBYnF0X7+bgNdBQwR7djkkSM3IifJ8cZwQwwF4IODkADW+VBDm0OWctVMbI5XJ5YD5gvqvluqDpeAZTI4oqcNWMJjZfJIAHJQgqhb5lUA)

`Cannot call 'update' with object literal bound to 'updateObject' because property 'name' is missing in object literal [1] but exists in object type [2] in property 'nested'. [prop-missing]`

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `$DeepShape` type as [seen in use here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCcAdhgE4CWAbngCYAquBAvGAN6phgl4DOGegC4OXbjwCGAWzwiBVEgHMANGO5wcGSqQkwAaroCueAIwB+ORUpLV4sBq079RvACYLYedZViAvqn9UGDwMMABjUitaOhFiMipopnwwNk5uXgFhDhJpWTAAIgAlPABHQ0pyejADGGN8-0DsZIASABE8PBwAZQALCXwAHgB5ESGAIwArPDCMAD4UsHGpmbAAMjBm3v68AealgFl+4eUwAAoBvVHJ6bnTvQBKFPm2ju6+wb1Zx4AfM4vZu6PFjzB6zWboJoEACqODoEkESxuCxenS2gziUXoSTw4NQERIAjAhlh8NYZ2JcIR1xmIhhlLwiJm9xE1DglDoT1E3HxmI5qTUYAAdMKeQl6CcBcLBRTSYyMLZxBlBDEuXYhSLImK6GZBUrxWABdwpTKqcsMDq9XQBf5uA10Ca8Kd2JaRM7ciJ8nwenBDDAOQg4OQANb5E4ObQ5Zy1Uwer0+v1gAPB+q+e6oB1Ol0ccNOGrGEwegMkADkoSTId8qaAA)

The code I used is

```
type $DeepShape<O: Object> = Object & $Shape<$ObjMap<O, (<V: Object>(V) => $DeepShape<V>) | (<V>(V) => V)>>
```

and is from [this Github thread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5262)

Here is the final result of the above code:

```
/* @flow */

type ContrivedType = {
  nested: {
    name: string,
    optionalValue1?: string,
    optionalValue2?: string,
  }
}

let contrived: ContrivedType = {
  nested: {name: "Required Value"}
}

type $DeepShape<O: Object> = Object & $Shape<$ObjMap<O, (<V: Object>(V) => $DeepShape<V>) | (<V>(V) => V)>>

type UpdateObject = $DeepShape<ContrivedType>

const update = (updateObject: UpdateObject): void => {
  contrived = {
    ...contrived, 
    ...updateObject,
    nested: {
      ...contrived?.nested, 
      ...updateObject?.nested
    }
  }
}

update({nested: {name: "should work", optionalValue1: "should work"}})
update({nested: {optionalValue1: "won't work"}})
```

Would love any feedback on any issues or concerns people may have.